# write and read html file from webview windows 8 store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have a requirement to produce reports in html (So they can be styles via css etc...) The application is a Windows 8 Store App.
I have created a template and am able to produce the html file. I initially saved it here 
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation
Great right?  wrong!  The WebView control will not read from that location!
I also tried writing to the Assets folder of my app.  Nope!  Permission Denied.
Windows 8 store apps have limited rights to the folder system.

Question:
Where can I put dynamically generated html files (run time) so that they can be read by the WebView Control?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has had this problem, or like me you are new to windows store development. Here is the answer (Got help from [pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com))

Code:

```
 StorageFile file = await destFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

       string url = "ms-appdata:///local/Estimates/" + fileName;
```

Comment: Correct: your InstalledLocation--where the package lives--is by design a read-only folder. Your AppData folders, on the other hand, are read-write. The Local, Temp, and Roaming appdata folders are, by design, the only places where an app can read/write freely.